# Listview item background image problem in my android application

Tags: android, image, listview, layout, background

I have in my application a listview with an adapter that uses different layouts for the items.

I want the result to be like in the attached exp_result.png.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/717/expresult.png/

But unfortunatly - I get like in result.png.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/839/resultf.png/

The problem is that image stretches on the screen not the way I wanted.
Any ideas?

Maybe other solution to this layout - maybe built in?

Drawables are in the links, since I cannot upload images. The original  picture is like in the first listview item in the exp_result.png. I want to use 1 picture for each - top, buttom and middle and to be used no matter the listview item size. XML is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/list_up" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can really really use some help here.

Yoav

Comment: Post your Layout and drawable xmls.

Comment: Drawables are in the links, since I cannot upload images. The original picture is like in the first listview item in the exp_result.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a good application of the 9-patch image type:

[9-Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

Comment: Good point, maybe this will actually fix all of your problems.